# iOS Game Center not working now app is live

Tags: ios, iphone, gamekit

I've just released my app on the App store tonight (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bird-hunter/id829810807?ls=1&mt=8﻿), it has a leaderboard that worked perfectly well in sandbox mode, but now shows up saying no items.

During the review process I was able to see another user on the leaderboard, presumable the person who tested the app. I have game center enabled in itunes connect.

Is this something that will take some time to kick in, or is there something else I have to do to make it work?

Comment: Did you find a solution for the problem? I have iAds in my apps and i know they can take a few days to "kick-in" is it the same with Game Center?

Answer (score 0):

I'd not submitted the Leader Board for approval to Apple with the app. I ended up doing some bug fixes to the app and then submitting the Leader Board for approval with the bug fixes, and then everything worked.

It's kind of a shame though as I had a big spike of downloads on the first day, and downloads didn't pick up again until the leader board stuff worked. I kind of wonder if I'd have got a lot more downloads had this been working straight away.